# В Qt Creator 4.11.0 based on Qt 5.14.0 под CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 не запускается debugger

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtcreator, centos7

В Qt Creator 4.11.0 based on Qt 5.14.0 установленной под CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 не запускается debugger.

Qt Creator и Qt установлены программой установки "Qt maintenance tool".

Текст программы на C++:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Run\n";
}
```

firewalld отключил и скрыл

Компилер: g++ 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)

Дебагер: GNU gdb Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-115.el7

Application output:

14:49:37: Checking available ports...

14:49:37: No device given

Из-за чего это может происходить?

Comment: а почему он какие-то порты ищет? вы там что какой-то remote настроить пытались? Device это обычно относится к удалённому, какому-нибудь линуксу типа embedded и т.п.

Comment: Вроде бы по-умолчанию конфигурация. То есть я создал новую, но поменял только компилятор и дебагер. Удалил также все шаги Deploy. Как установить чтобы выполнял отладку на локальном компьютере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разобрался вроде.

Я создавал новый Kit. По-умолчанию он создаётся с Device type: "Generic Linux device". Причём в этом случае в пункте Device выбрать "Local PC" нельзя. А если ничего не выбрать, то возникает описанная выше ситуация.

Решение:
Tools -> Options.... -> Kits -> Ваш kit:

- Device type: **Desktop**
- Device: **Local PC (default for Desctop)**

И дебагер запустится нормально )